# Regular Expression doesn't Match with string

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to use Regular Expressions to find a string sequence inside a string.

The pattern i am looking for is:

dd.dd.dddd dd:dd:dd //d is a digit from 0-9

my regex is:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"(\d[0-9]{2}.\d[0-9]{2}.\d[0-9]{4}\s\d[0-9]{2}:\d[0-9]{2}:\d[0-9]{2})$");
```

I am now trying to check, if the string "27.11.2014 09:14:59" is Matching to the regex, but sadly it isn't matching.

```
string str= "27.11.2014 09:14:59";
Regex r = new Regex(@"(\d[0-9]{2}.\d[0-9]{2}.\d[0-9]{4}\s\d[0-9]{2}:\d[0-9]{2}:\d[0-9]{2})$");
test = r.IsMatch(str,0);

//output: test=false
```

Anyone knows why the String is not Matching with that regular expression?

Comment: You might need to double-escape the escapes (use two backslashes "\\" instead of one).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\d[0-9]{2}` matches *three* digits:

```
\d      first digit
[0-9]   second digit
{2}     causes the previous expression ([0-9]) to match again
```

If you remove all occurences of `\d`, your pattern should work. You should escape all dots `.` though, because right now they match *any* character, not just a `.`.

Answer (score 0):

As Rawing already said, the upper Regular expression is trying to match 3 digits instead of one. for everyone who want to know how the regular expression should look like:

```
@"(\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})$"
```

Thats working, at least for me.

Comment: You should have read his full answer and escaped your `.` characters.